# RSA Encryption using PHP and Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to JavaScript and wanted to know how to display to text-box from the below code. I am having a hard time to transferring the variable encrypted info to a text-box using JavaScript. If that's not possible then how can I display the information from `$('#feedback').html(data);` to  the `textbox`.

```
<script>

    function encrypt() {
        var publickey = "<?=publicKeyToHex($privatekey)?>";
        var rsakey = new RSAKey();
        rsakey.setPublic(publickey, "10001");
        var enc = rsakey.encrypt($('#plaintext').val());

        $.get('index.php?encrypted='+enc, function(data) {
            var encryptedinfo = $('#feedback').html(data);
            encryptedinfo.value;
        });

        return;
    }

</script>

<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="span4">
    <form class="form-horizontal" method="post">
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Plaintext</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" name="plaintext" id="plaintext" placeholder="enter something">
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<div class="span4">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="encrypt()">Encrypt</button>
</div>
<br/>
```

Comment: Do you want to set the encrypted value back to the `plaintext`??

Comment: @SujeetSinha yes i want to

Comment: Did you really mean `publicKeyToHex($privatekey)`?

Comment: Assuming you have the encrypted value in the `data`, you can simply use `$("#plaintext").val(data)`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You've provided the code, but haven't shown what's supposed to be wrong with it. Please [edit] your question provide example inputs, outputs and expected outputs.

Comment: @SujeetSinha Thanks. I managed to pull it off.

Comment: Did it work using the method I suggested? If so, I'll post it as an answer so that others can refer it..

Comment: @SujeetSinha Yes it did

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the encrypted value in the `data`, you can simply use `$("#plaintext").val(data)`.